# Oracle ORDS Filter Query Date is NULL

Tags: oracle, oracle-ords

I use `ORACLE ORDS`. I have a collection with dates and want to filter all Dates with null values with the **q** parameter.

```json
{"cancellation_date":"$null"}
```

I get an

> ORA-01858 error

```json
{"start_date":{"$eq":{"$date":"$null"}}}
```

gives me an Bad Request.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think I just found a solution

{"cancellation_date": {"$null": null}}

Comment: Correct! As shown in the Docs (#### NULL operator ($null) { "ENAME": {"$null": null}})  here - https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/21.3/aelig/developing-REST-applications.html#GUID-8D2CA518-2F13-4503-8DBF-62C5F2C681B7